# How can I turn my flutter app left or right of landscape based on user phone orientation?

Tags: android, flutter, uiinterfaceorientation

I made my application go into landscape mode when using

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
]);
```

But I cannot make it turn landscape right or left specifically based on which way the user is holding the phone.

I do not want to from portrait to landscape, I just want to be able to go to the two different sides of landscapes even when auto rotate is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency in your pubsec.yaml file

```
    dependencies:
  native_device_orientation: ^0.2.0
```

Run following command or terminal to get the dependency package

```
flutter pub get
```

Import the following class, as

```
import 'package:native_device_orientation/native_device_orientation.dart';
```

And here is the rest of the example code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:native_device_orientation/native_device_orientation.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool useSensor = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Native Orientation example app'),
            actions: <Widget>[Switch(value: useSensor, onChanged: (val) => setState(() => useSensor = val))],
          ),
// encapsulating your Screen UI with NativeDeviceOrientationReader is must.
              body: NativeDeviceOrientationReader(
                builder: (context) {
                  NativeDeviceOrientation orientation = NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
                  print("Received new orientation: $orientation");
                  return Center(child: Text('Native Orientation: $orientation\n'));
                },
                useSensor: useSensor,
              ),
              floatingActionButton: Builder(
                builder: (context) {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        child: Text("Sensor"),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          NativeDeviceOrientation orientation =
                          await NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator().orientation(useSensor: true);
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text("Native Orientation read: $orientation"),
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        child: Text("UI"),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          NativeDeviceOrientation orientation =
                              await NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator().orientation(useSensor: false);
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text("Native Orientation read: $orientation"),
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              )),
        );
      }
    }
```